# Should we mention all the hypotheses in the results part in an academic paper?

Tags: writing-style

Normally, in an academic paper, we can see that in the Hypothesis development section, researchers normally raise some hypotheses.

For example:

H1: A affects B

After running empirical regression, I am wondering if it is a must to repeat that "**the result confirm the hypothesis 1 that A affects B**" or if we just need to mention that "**the result shows that A affects B**" ?

I ask this question because:

I thought of not writing the hypothesis number because I do not want my audience to need to go back to the hypothesis development to see what I wrote, which may drive my audiences' attention away (suggested by [McCLOSKEY, p.192](http://www.deirdremccloskey.com/docs/pdf/Article_86.pdf)). On the other hand, I thought if we do not confirm the hypothesis at the Result section, it means that we did not close the case we opened.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter. Look up some papers in your field and see how they handle it. However, if you formulate your results like you did including the hypothesis number, readers do not need to go back since you already confirm in the same sentence what the hypothesis was.